# UIImageJPEGRepresentation giving 2x images on retina display

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have this code, which creates an image, and then adds some effects to it and sizes it down to make `largeThumbnail`.

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.originalImage];
thumbnail = createLargeThumbnailFromImage(originalImage);

NSLog(@"thumbnail: %f", thumbnail.size.height);
NSData *thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 1.0);
```

Later on:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.largeThumbnail];
NSLog(@"thumbnail 2: %f", image.size.height);
```

NSLog returns:

```
thumbnail: 289.000000
thumbnail 2: 578.000000
```

As you can see, when it converts the image back from data, it makes it 2x the size. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Large thumbnail code:

```
UIImage *createLargeThumbnailFromImage(UIImage *image) {
    UIImage *resizedImage;

        resizedImage = [image imageScaledToFitSize:LARGE_THUMBNAIL_SIZE];

    CGRect largeThumbnailRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedImage.size.width, resizedImage.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(resizedImage.size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Image
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, resizedImage.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, largeThumbnailRect, resizedImage.CGImage);

    //Border
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGRect innerRect = rectForRectWithInset(largeThumbnailRect, 1.5);
    CGMutablePathRef borderPath = createRoundedRectForRect(innerRect, 0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3);
    CGContextAddPath(context, borderPath);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIImage *thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: Do _you_ have any ideas why it may be happening? What have you tried to debug this yourself?

Comment: I've put in additional NSLogs, which revealed that it happens at the point where the image gets converted back from NSData.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing the part where you load the second image:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:self.largeThumbnail];
```

with this one:

```
UIImage *jpegImage = [UIImage imageWithData:self.largeThumbnail];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:jpegImage.CGImage scale:originalImage.scale orientation:jpegImage.imageOrientation];
```

What happens here is that the image scale is not set, so you get double image dimensions.

Comment: I'm having the same problem (getting 2x image when converting back from NSData *). Could you elaborate more? For me, `originalImage.scale` returns 1 so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: "scale is not set, so you get double image dimensions."..This line helps me...Thank you..

Comment: I was passing "0" as a scale to UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to create a scaled image. Passing originalImage.scale fixed it. Thanks!!