# How to save resized images?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimage, file-manager

Good evening

I am trying to save the resized images in Documents Directory, to avoid having to resize every time it is called.

Analyzing the problem is just when I use the following line:

```
let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image, 1.0)
```

It appears that UIImageJPEGRepresentation undoes the changes made to the image and thus saves the image in the same ratio.

Anyone know a way to fix this?

Below the code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myImageName = "image_10001.jpg"
        let imagePath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: myImageName)
        if let image = UIImage(named:"image_10001")?.resizedImage(newSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size){
            print("Image : \(image.size.height)")
            _ = saveImage(image: image, path: imagePath)
        }
        if let loadedImage = loadImageFromPath(path: imagePath){
            print("Screen: \(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)")
            print("Image Size: \(loadedImage.size.height)")
    //            let image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(loadedImage, 0.9)
    //            let imgRes = UIImage(data: image!)?.resizedImage(newSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    ////            
    //            let load = loadedImage.resizedImage(newSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
    //            
    //            print("Load: \(load.size.height)")
    //            
    //            _  = saveImage(image: load, path: imagePath)
    //            
             imgView.image =  loadedImage
    //
    //            imgView.image = UIImage(data: image!)?.resizedImage(newSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
        let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
        if image == nil {
            print("missing image at: \(path)")
        }
        print("Loading image from path: \(path)") // this is just for you to see the path in case you want to go to the directory, using Finder.
        return image
    }
    func getDocumentsURL() -> URL {
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        return documentsURL
    }
    func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {
        let fileURL = getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent(filename)
        return fileURL.path
    }
    func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{
        print("Save")
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    //        let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)   // if you want to save as JPEG
        let img = UIImage(data:jpgImageData!)
     //        
          print("SIMG: \(String(describing: img?.size.height))")
        do {
            _ = try jpgImageData?.write(to: url, options: .atomicWrite)
            print("Save Success")
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

---

```
extension UIImage {
    /// Returns a image that fills in newSize
    func resizedImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        // Guard newSize is different
        guard self.size != newSize else { return self }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
    /// Returns a resized image that fits in rectSize, keeping it's aspect ratio
    /// Note that the new image size is not rectSize, but within it.
    func resizedImageWithinRect(rectSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let widthFactor = size.width / rectSize.width
        let heightFactor = size.height / rectSize.height
        var resizeFactor = widthFactor
        if size.height > size.width {
            resizeFactor = heightFactor
        }
        let newSize = CGSize(width:size.width/resizeFactor, height:size.height/resizeFactor)
        let resized = resizedImage(newSize: newSize)
        return resized
    }
    var jpeg: Data? {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self, 1)   // QUALITY min = 0 / max = 1
    }
    var png: Data? {
        return UIImagePNGRepresentation(self)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    var uiImage: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(data: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImageJpgRepresentation doubles image resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704615/uiimagejpgrepresentation-doubles-image-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some "old" image inside your documents directory that was saved with some older code you had (not resized).

I assume that because the code you posted will not save any new images, because of this line:

```
if let image = UIImage(named:"image_10001")?.resizedImage(newSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size){
    //resize code
}
```

I think you wanted to use here same image name just taken from bundle:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: myImageName)?.resizedImage(newSize: UIScreen.main.bounds.size){
    //resize code
}
```

You can Reset Simulator Content and confirm that no image will be loaded with the code you posted here.

Comment: So Mrs Krukowski the code works fine, the problem is exactly i call 

let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image, 1.0) 

Before this line my image has the proportions resized but when i call this line and set a image for instance let img = UIImage(data: jpg).size.height, this image has the normal size.

All the rest is working fine

Comment: For me all worked well.
Save shows 2208.0, Loading image shows: 2208.0.
What your prints are showing ?

Comment: So i found the problem Mrs Krukowski

In this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704615/uiimagejpgrepresentation-doubles-image-resolution?noredirect=1&lq=1

The UIImageJPEGRepresentation double the image size  because the scale is not set.

So my image when i resized appear  for instance 1000 when i load the image appear 2000 but the scale is 1 and dont 2.

So anyway i need to resize the image

Comment: Ah ok didn't expect that. You can close the question then